# Passing html <img> components as a parameter property into <li> tags with react.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm transforming a string into a series of image tags as follows:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < cardCollection.length; i++) {
  cardCollection[i].manaCost = cardCollection[i].manaCost.replace(/\{([0-z]+)\}/g, "<img src='\\data\\img\\$1.png' height='20px'/>");
}
```

This transforms something like {1}{G} into

```html
<img src='./data/img/1.png' height='20px'/><img src='./data/img/G.png' height='20px'/>
```

I presume the path is set correctly since the js file this is in lives in the same folder as the 'data' folder (and I've tried with and without the . before /data). I then want to insert this html into an existing < li> component:

```js
< ul onClick = {this.handleListClick} > 
{ cardCollection.map(function(card) {
    if (card.manaCost != undefined) {
        return <li>{card.name} {card.manaCost} </li>; 
    }
    else {
        return <li>{card.name}</li > ;
    }
  })
} < /ul>
```

This 'works' in that it shows me the raw html and the image tags, but not the actual images I'm trying to get. Removing the {} from around card.manaCost just gives me 'card.manaCost'. Assuming my path is correct, what do I have to do to get it to parse it as actual HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your HTML string to be parsed, you can use the [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) property:

```
<ul onClick = {this.handleListClick}> 
{ cardCollection.map(function(card) {
    if (card.manaCost != undefined) {
        var html = card.name + ' ' + card.manaCost;
        return <li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}} />;
    }
    else {
        return <li>{card.name}</li>;
    }
  })
} </ul>
```

However, notice how bad that looks. This is intentional, because the React team doesn't want you to use it:

> Improper use of the `innerHTML` can open you up to a [cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack. Sanitizing user input for display is notoriously error-prone, and failure to properly sanitize is one of the [leading causes of web vulnerabilities](https://owasptop10.googlecode.com/files/OWASP%20Top%2010%20-%202013.pdf) on the internet.

I recommend not mutating the array (i.e. removing that `for` loop) and creating images as React elements directly:

```
<ul onClick = {this.handleListClick}> 
{ cardCollection.map(function(card, i) {
    var manaCost;
    if (card.manaCost) {
      manaCost = card.manaCost
        .match(/\{[0-z]+\}/g)
        .map(function (basename, i) {
          var src = './data/img/' + basename.substring(1, basename.length - 1) + '.png';
          return <img key={i} src={src} height='20px' />;
        });
    }
    return <li key={i}>{card.name} {manaCost}</li>;
  })
} </ul>
```

Comment: This works almost perfectly. However, since the loop that creates the img tags is called every time I update cardCollection (which is every time a new letter appears in the search bar), it's trying to do a match on something it already changed into one or more img components. What's the safest way to stop it from doing that?

Comment: @IronWaffleMan the safest way is to stop mutating that value, and save it to a different property or different object. `card.manaImage = parseCost(card.manaCost);`. React will try to parse `manaCost`, and it will be able to do so.

Comment: @IronWaffleMan edited. Let me know if the new solution works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not wholly sure what the string-manipulation is doing for you, nor why you need it.

If you are transpiling JSX, there's no reason to stop transpiling it, inside of your interpolated sections.

```
const freeCard = (card, i) => <li key={i}>{ card.title }</li>;
const pricedCard = (card, i) => {
  const src = `./data/img/${card.src}.png`;
  return <li key={i}>{ card.title } <img src={ src } width="20px" /></li>;
};

render () {
  <ul >
    { cards.map((card, i) => card.src ? pricedCard(card) : freeCard(card) }
  </ul>
}
```

That should work just fine.
Note that I'm using ES6 template strings (to build the `src`),
and ES6 Arrow functions (but a `function freeCard (card, i) { return <li key={i}>{card.title}</li>; }` is equivalent).

If you're using Babel to transpile (you should be), and you're using a sufficiently new version of React, then the above should suffice.

The only piece not demonstrated is changing all of the string manipulation into:

```
const parseCost = cost => cost.replace(/\{[0-z]+\}/, "$1");
cards.forEach(card => card.src = parseCost(card.manaCost));
```

Your real problem is that React is preventing you from injecting strings as HTML.
If you consider why, it should make sense; React doesn't want to insert HTML by default, if you decide to make a forum, or add blog comments, open to user-input.

You can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute of an element, feeding it an object with an `__html` property...

```
function pricedCard (card, i) {
  const htmlString = "" + card.title + " <img src=\"./data/img/" + card.src + "\" />";
  const content = {
    __html: htmlString
  };

  return <li key={i} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ content } />;
}
```

But as you can see, that's probably less like what you were hoping to accomplish.

Personally, I'd do something like:

```
const FreeCard = ({ title }) => <li >{ title }</li>;
const PricedCard = ({ title, src }) => <li >{ title } <img src={ src } /></li>;

render () {
  const list = cards.map((card, i) => card.src ?
    <PricedCard key={i} {...card} /> :
    <FreeCard key={i} {...card} />
  );
  return <ul>{ list }</ul>;
}
```

I'd go a little further to factor out the `<li>` from my structure, but the card without a cost has no root structure in your example.